# Start process with environment variable

Tags: c#, process, environment-variables

I want to start a process with the following path.

> "ProgramFiles(x86)\Philips Speech\Device Control Center PDCC.exe"

When I type this into the console the process starts as expected but when I try to do it in code I get the following exception:

> the system cannot find the file specified

This I my code so far:

```
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Philips Speech\Device Control Center PDCC.exe");
Debug.Assert(startInfo.EnvironmentVariables.ContainsKey("ProgramFiles(x86)")) //Is true
new Process(startInfo).Start(); //<- exception occures here
```

Does anybody have an idea if I can do this directly by giving the ProcessStartInfo class the environment variable or if I have to parse it before doing so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
string path = Environment.ExpanEnvironmentVariables("%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Philips Speech\Device Control Center PDCC.exe");
var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(path);
new Process(startInfo).Start();
```

This way you can use the variables (e.g. `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%`) and not depend on the folder being in `C:\` or something.

Comment: As I saving my path including the environment variable in the settings I'll go for your solution also because it's clean

Answer (score 7):

You should use this to get the path to Program Files:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86)
```

[Special folders enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder).

Answer (score 2):

The constructor just sets the `fileName` property to what you pass, so yes you will need to resolve the environment variable first.

From [the source code for ProcessStartInfo](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/ProcessStartInfo.cs):

```
public ProcessStartInfo(string fileName) {
     this.fileName = fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this, if you want the same behavior like Start->Run

```
Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%\System32")
```